# EOF before EOF in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-io

I had this snippet in a program (in Visual Studio 2005):

```
if(_eof(fp->_file))
{
    break;
}
```

It broke the enclosing loop when eof was reached. But the program was not able to parse the last few thousand chars in file. So, in order to find out what was happening, I did this:

```
if(_eof(fp->_file))
{
    cout<<ftell(fp)<<endl;
    break;
}
```

Now the answer that I got from ftell was different (and smaller) than the actual file-size (which isn't expected). I thought that Windows might have some problem with the file, then I did this:

```
if(_eof(fp->_file))
{
    cout<<ftell(fp)<<endl;
    fseek(fp, 0 , SEEK_END);
    cout<<ftell(fp)<<endl;
    break;
}
```

Well, the fseek() gave the right answer (equal to the file-size) and the initial ftell() failed (as previously told).

Any idea about what could be wrong here?

**EDIT:** The file is open in "rb" mode.

Comment: Is this a binary file or a text file? Have you opened it in the correct mode (binary or text)?

Comment: It is opened in binary mode...

Comment: Open the file in your favourite hex editor, go to that byte, and see what's there. Then you will have your answer.

Comment: @Tomalak The last byte on the location where this thing happens is 8C, and the next byte is ED. That suggests something to you?

Comment: Never mind; Luther is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably use `_eof()` on a file descriptor obtained from a `FILE*`, because `FILE*` streams are buffered. It means that `fp` has sucked `fp->_file` dry and stores the remaining byte in its internal buffer. Eventually `fp->_file` is at eof position, while `fp` still has bytes for you to read. Use `feof()` *after* a read operation to determine if you are at the end of a file and be careful if you mix functions which operate on `FILE*` with those operating on integer file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using _eof() directly on the descriptor if your file I/O operations are on the FILE stream that wraps it.  There is buffering that takes place and the underlying descriptor will hit end-of-file before your application has read all the data from the FILE stream.

In this case, ftell(fp) is reporting the state of the stream and you should be using feof(fp) to keep them in the same I/O domain.